# Existence of an orthogonal basis of a subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, orthonormal

The theorem says, "If $P$ be a subspace of a finite dimensional Euclidean subspace of $V$, then $V=P\oplus P^\perp$.
My book starts the proof like this:

> Let $P\ne \{{\theta}\}$ and let $\{\beta_1,\beta_2,\ldots,\beta_r\}$ be an orthogonal basis of $P$.

And the proof goes on.
Now my question is **what ensures that a subspace must have an orthogonal or orthonormal basis**? Does a basis necessarily need to be orthogonal or orthonormal?

Comment: No, the basis doesn't need to be orthogonal or orthonormal. But you can use Gram-Schmidt process to obtain the orthogonal basis from an arbitrary basis.

Comment: @MathFail what advantages should one get if chooses to have an orthonormal basis instead of orthogonal basis? because the only differences are $\langle\alpha_i,\alpha_i\rangle=1$ in case of orthonormal basis and $\theta$ cannot be in the orthonormal basis

Comment: @MathFail moreover I cannot include $\theta$ in a basis

Comment: Yes, the orthonormal basis is normalized to $1$ for the inner product.

Comment: Just to explain the algorithm geometrically you take a vector $v$, normalize it to say, $u$ since it's a unit vector then take the orthogonal projection of some other vector $w$ onto it. Calling the projection $Pw$ then we have that $w-Pw$ is orthogonal to $u$. We now normalize this vector, and repeat the process on some other new vector with each orthonormal basis vector we've found so far. Since the space is finite dimensional this process ends.

Comment: What is $\theta$ ?

Comment: @Raskolnikov obviously the null vector. If $P$ contains only the null vector, then $P$ is orthogonal to itself.